# Use SCP from local machine to recursively copy current working directory to remote?

Tags: scp, recursive, pwd

Trying to do something like (in pseudo-unix):

`scp -r <pwd> username@remote.com:~/<dirname of toplevel>`

In other words, I'm trying to copy the current directory I'm in locally (and the contents) over to remote while sticking the very last path segment from "pwd" commands output onto `/home/user/<here>` in the remote.

I'm shaky in my unix commands so I figured I'd ask vs. experiment this time to avoid damage

Comment: Why doesn’t `scp -r . user@remote:` do what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ scp -pr "$(pwd)" user@remote.example.com:"$(basename $(pwd) )/"
```

Comment: You can probably simplify this with `scp -pr $(pwd) user@remote.example.com:` -- I think it'll automatically create the same-named directory.

Comment: `pwd` shows the entire path.  Probably not the intended effect.

Comment: I agree, `pwd` does return the entire path, but `scp` doesn't try to recreate the entire path on the remote size, just the last element of the path (at least with my experimentation).

Comment: thank you, it will still get me far enough without 'awk/sed'

Comment: If the current working directory has spaces in its name this command still throws errors: extra arguments to `basename` and, even with `"$(basename "$(pwd)")"` a cryptic "scp: ambiguous target" — because quoting locally a remote path is not enough, quotes should also be sent to the remote host, e.g. `scp -pr "$(pwd)" user@remote_host:"'""$(basename "$(pwd)")""'"`. But, actually, the simpler `scp -pr "$(pwd)" user@remote_host:` seems to just work.